# Numeric string comparison with 17 bytes not returning different on PHP 5.3.27

Tags: php, comparison

While I understand the difference and the possibilities to compare numeric strings, casting and other stuff, something happened yesterday that, as I'm unable to read C code I didn't dig into PHP source files, doesn't seems to be documented.

Situation is, using PHP 5.3.27:

With a numeric string of 16 bytes:

```
var_dump("1111111111111111" != "1111111111111112") === true
```

with a numeric string of 17 bytes, I just added another 1 at the beggining:

```
var_dump("11111111111111111" != "11111111111111112"); === false
```

But changing the last character:

```
var_dump("11111111111111111" != "11111111111111114"); === true
```

Why? 
What happens with 16 and 17 bytes string?

Comment: var_dump("11111111111111111" != "11111111111111112") === true for me

Comment: (php 5.6) 'hocvt$ php -r 'var_dump("11111111111111111" != "11111111111111112");' =>>> bool(true)'

Comment: For me all three are true which is correct. Are you sure you gave us exactly code you have?

Comment: @nospor yes I'm sure. I just retested and got the same results I wrote. I'm using PHP 5.3.27

Comment: Well, I just tested on 5.6.8 and I got all true too. I presume it's a php core bug then. Just another note, converting to int, with `intval()` the values of 17 bytes, I got the same value as my `PHP_MAX_VAL`, yet comparing them with `!=` I got `false`, even if both on `var_dump()` showed me the same value. Running `floatval` though, I got `1.111111...E+16`, and comparing them with `!=` it returned `true`.

Comment: Half-guessed loose answer: PHP is casting the numeric strings to numbers, which exceed `PHP_INT_MAX` **on your 32-bit build** of PHP (64-bit builds works fine), which overflows the numbers to floats, at which point comparisons get a little… imprecise. As a solution: use `!==`.